# Google User Accounts

Tags: google-app-engine

```
            package clock;

            import java.io.IOException;
            import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
            import java.util.Date;
            import java.util.SimpleTimeZone;
            import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
            import javax.servlet.ServletException;
            import javax.servlet.http.*;

            import com.google.appengine.api.users.User;
            import com.google.appengine.api.users.UserService;
            import com.google.appengine.api.users.UserServiceFactory;

            @SuppressWarnings("serial")
            public class ClockServlet extends HttpServlet {
                public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req,
                                  HttpServletResponse resp)
                    throws IOException, ServletException {
                    SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSSSSS");
                    fmt.setTimeZone(new SimpleTimeZone(0, ""));

                    UserService userService = UserServiceFactory.getUserService();
                    User user = userService.getCurrentUser();
                    String loginUrl = userService.createLoginURL("/");
                    String logoutUrl = userService.createLogoutURL("/");

                    req.setAttribute("user", user);
                    req.setAttribute("loginUrl", loginUrl);
                    req.setAttribute("logoutUrl", logoutUrl);
                    req.setAttribute("currentTime", fmt.format(new Date()));

                    resp.setContentType("text/html");

                    RequestDispatcher jsp = req.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/home.jsp");
                    jsp.forward(req, resp);
                }
            }



            <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
            <html>
              <head>
                <title>The Time Is...</title>
              </head>
              <body>
                <c:choose>
                  <c:when test="${user != null}">
                    <p>
                      Welcome, ${user.email}!
                      You can <a href="${logoutUrl}">sign out</a>.
                    </p>
                  </c:when>
                  <c:otherwise>
                    <p>
                      Welcome!
                      <a href="${loginUrl}">Sign in or register</a> to customize.
                    </p>
                  </c:otherwise>
                </c:choose>
                <p>The time is: ${currentTime}</p>
              </body>
            </html>
```

Since I was logged in to my gmail at the time I ran the example I was hoping to see Welcome but it goes to sign in and register even though I am logged in to gmail. Could there be some problem with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Applications do not have automatic access to your gmail account, nor are you automatically logged into your app if you are logged into your gmail. That would be pretty dangerous - all GAE apps could collect user emails if user visited their Url.

Users still need to login into your app, e.g. go through a federated login.